# Slow load time from asp.net core static files when using service fabric and reverse proxy

Tags: azure, reverse-proxy, azure-service-fabric

I have provision a service fabric cluster using the template. And created a application containing a asp.net core service. I have a azure load balancer pointing to service fabric revers proxy that pointing to the asp.net core service.

Now to the strange part when I try to load 1,3 MB javascript file from the service it take 22 seconds on my 100 MBit connection. If I insted point the load blancer to the service in service fabric nodes it take 500 ms on the same compute calling the same service in service fabric.

If I call the same url on one of the service fabric nodes they take 300 ms if I use the revers proxy url.If I use the load balanced url pointing directly to service on the nodes it take 100 ms.

All the times is time to first byte. Is there a problem with azure load balancer and service fabric reverse-proxy?

Comment: Did you manage to find anymore information or an issue? I'm currently experiencing the same behavior.

Comment: This was a bug and is now fixed by Microsoft in Service fabric version 5.5.232.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug and is now fixed by Microsoft in Service fabric version 5.5.232.0